# Issues with Arrow and Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to plot a simple picture: a plane with a circle in it, and three vectors in the curve. *Mathematica* keeps saying that the array "has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list" and I don't know what it wants me to do. My code so far is:

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[s], Sqrt[3] Sin[s]/2, Sin[s]/2 }, {s, 0, 3 π/2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Plot3D[y/Sqrt[3], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    Mesh -> Automatic, 
    MeshStyle -> 
      Directive[RGBColor[.3, .32, 0.], Opacity[.1], AbsoluteThickness[.755], DotDashed], 
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[.82, .69, 0.]], 
  Graphics3D[
    Arrow[{{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, 
           {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}}]], 
  Graphics3D[
    Arrow[{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, 
          {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {Sqrt[2]/2, -Sqrt[6]/4, -Sqrt[2]/4}]], 
  Graphics3D[
    Arrow[{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, 
          {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {0, -1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}]], 
  Boxed -> False,  
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1.5}}]
```

I know I don't need to use a separate `Graphics3D` expression for every arrow, but my code doesn't do what I want if I put everything together like:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Arrow[{{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, 
         {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}}],
  Arrow[{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, 
        {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {Sqrt[2]/2, -Sqrt[6]/4, -Sqrt[2]/4}], 
  Arrow[{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, 
        {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {0, -1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}]}]
```

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. You had problem with too few `{` in the `Arrow` calls

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[s], Sqrt[3] Sin[s]/2, Sin[s]/2}, {s, 0, 3 π/2}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot3D[y/Sqrt[3], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.3`, 0.32`, 0.`], Opacity[0.1`], AbsoluteThickness[0.755`], DotDashed], 
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.8200000000000001`, 0.6900000000000001`, 0.`]], 
 Graphics3D[Arrow[{{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}}]], 
 Graphics3D[Arrow[{{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {Sqrt[2]/2, -Sqrt[6]/4, -Sqrt[2]/4}}]], 
 Graphics3D[Arrow[{{-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4}, {-Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[6]/4, Sqrt[2]/4} + {0, -1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}]], 
 Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1.5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ref comment: The third arrow is there. Just need to rotate the plot to see it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I got something similar to this here, but the tips weren't showing. Yours is better, thanks. However, we had three arrows, and our pictures only show two of them. I tried messing with `PlotRange` to see if the third arrow would show, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: @IvoTerek I just pasted your code as is, just fixed the syntax error. The third arrow is there, you just need to rotate the 3D to see it. it is hiding. It is your arrows, so the directions are setup by you and I did not change these.

Comment: You are right. I thought that the plane was more transparent. Thanks. Now I'll try to make this better `:)`